# SSIS Lookup give no match always for Oracle OLEDB connection

Tags: oracle, ssis, etl, lookup, data-migration

I have flat file data source and Oracle Destination. When I use lookup transformation to validate some data exists in certain tables, it always gives no match. I have converted the data type in derived column, it exactly matches with the table data type. Data type of the column is Unicode string. Exact matches leads to no match output. I am using native SSIS OLEDB connection for Oracle. Please help.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check your case sensitivity. Sreekanth will not match sreekanth or SREEKANTH

Check for trailing spaces, even in variable length columns.

Those are the two biggest stumbling blocks. If those are not it, then edit your question with the source table definition, the lookup table definition and an appropriate insert statement for both so we can help identify the specifics of what is awry.

Comment: I have added screenshots to the question to clarify the cases you mentioned. As you can see in the screenshot, I am trimming the spaces and matches the columns in upper case. Data type also matches. Do you find any gaps?

Comment: Excellent updates to your question - what is an example department id that exists in both systems that is not matching?

Comment: I even tried with simply 'XYZ'.